# How to list all 2013 workflows in SharePoint using powershell/c#

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint-2013, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

Hi is there any way to retrieve all 2013 workflows to SharePoint Site? We have this problem regarding our server where WorkFlow Manager 2013 uses all our server resources causing 100% CPU Usage and we need to know what are the workflows created by our users causing this.

As of now I have below code to retrieve all WF 2010 to our sites below:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0
$site=Get-SPSite("mysite dot com");

#Initialize Workflow Count variable
$workflowcount = 0

#Foreach loop to loop through all webs, and lists with workflow associations, and exclude workflows that have previous versions and write findings to .csv file.

function Get-Workflows()
{
 foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
 {
 foreach($list in $web.Lists)
 {
 foreach($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
 {
 if ($wf.Name -notlike "*Previous Version*")
 {
 $hash = @{"[URL]"=$web.Url;"[List Name]"=$list.Title;"[Workflow]"=$wf.Name}
 New-Object PSObject -Property $hash | Sort-Object

 }
 }
 }
 }
}

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
 foreach($list in $web.Lists)
 {
 foreach($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
 {
 if ($wf.Name -notlike "*Previous Version*")
 {
 $workflowcount += 1
 }
 }
 }
}

Get-Workflows | Export-csv C:\Users\Documents\rey.csv
"Workflow Count " + $workflowcount >> C:\Users\Documents\rey.csv

$site.Dispose()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to get all 2013 workflows in a site.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity $url
$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($web)
$defSevice = $wfm.GetWorkflowDeploymentService()
$wfDefs = $defSevice.EnumerateDefinitions($false)
foreach ($wfDef in $wfDefs){
$wfDef.properties
}
```

$wfDef.properties will list you all properties concerning the workflow. Like RestrictToScope which give you the GUID of associated list.